# php include wont work from online server

Tags: php

What is the problem following code ?

```
include_once("theme/login_theme/$loginTheme/landing_first.php");
```

The code is working fine in my localhost but when i upload my files from the online server this code doesn't worked. What is the problem here ?

Comment: Are all the files and folders in the include in the correct casing? Some OS's don't care about casing while other OS's do. So if you're developing on a OS that doesn't care and your include is using the wrong casing, it won't work if you upload it to a server that does.

Comment: $loginTheme, this is variable or folder name?

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan That is folder name variable.

Comment: Since I don't seem to get any answer to my question, I'm out...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry, I will try to understand your question. All file is correct casing yes and i am developing my script from OS.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the error try require_once instead of include_once,
in general, cases if the code does not work on the server you need to check:
The character case
The file if exists
The string and variables,

```
require_once("./theme/login_theme/".$loginTheme."/landing_first.php");
```

Hope this will be helpful,